# In my BST implementation,my findNode function not returning parent location to its calling function

Tags: c++

While implementing Binary search tree, i tried to have a custom find member function (findNode), which can provide me node location as well as parent location, But it failed to return it to calling function.

While implementing Binary search tree, i tried to have a custom find member function (findNode), which can provide me node location as well as parent location.
If i check inside findNode, it is able to find parent location. But it failed to return it to calling function.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    struct node* left;
    int data;
    struct node* right;
};

typedef struct node myNode;

class myTree
{
    myNode* root;

    void inorderUtil(myNode* rt);
    public:
    myNode* createNode(int num);
    myTree():root(NULL){};
    void inorder();
    //void postorder();
    //void preorder();
    void findNode(int num,myNode* par,myNode* loc);
    void insertNode(int num);
    void displayroot(){cout<<root->data<<endl;}
};

void myTree::inorder()
{
    inorderUtil(root);
}
void myTree::inorderUtil(myNode* rt)
{
    if(rt != NULL)
    {
        inorderUtil(rt->left);
        cout<<rt->data<<endl;
        inorderUtil(rt->right);
    }
}

myNode* myTree::createNode(int num)
{
    myNode* nd= new myNode();

    nd->data=num;
    nd->left=NULL;
    nd->right=NULL;

    return nd;

}

void myTree::findNode(int num,myNode* par,myNode* loc)
{
    cout<<"Searching for "<<num<<endl;
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        par=NULL;
        loc=NULL;
        //cout<<"tree is empty"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    if(root->data==num)
    {
        par=NULL;
        loc=root;
        return;
    }

    //cout<<"tree is non empty and data not at root"<<endl;
    myNode* r=root;
    par=root;
    loc=NULL;

    while((r->left != NULL) || (r->right != NULL))
    {
        if(r->left!=NULL && (r->left->data ==num))
        {
            par=r;
            loc=r->left;
            break;
        }
        else if(r->right!=NULL && (r->right->data ==num))
        {
            par=r;
            loc=r->right;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            par = r;
            if(num < r->data)
                r = r->left;
            else
                r = r->right;
        }
    }

    cout<<"parent is ="<<par->data<<endl;
}



void myTree::insertNode(int num)
{


    myNode* par=NULL;
    myNode* loc=NULL;
    findNode(num,par,loc);
    if(par !=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"in insert parent is ="<<par->data<<endl;
    }
    if(loc != NULL)
    {
        cout<<num<<" is already in tree, Aborting insertion "<<endl;
    }
    else    
    {
        myNode *nd= createNode(num);
            if(par == NULL)
            {
                root=nd;
            }
            else
            {
                if(par->left == NULL && par->data >num)
                    par->left =nd;
                if(par->right == NULL && par->data <num)
                    par->right =nd;
            }
    }

}
int main()
{
    myTree tr;

    tr.insertNode(50);
    tr.displayroot();
    myNode* par=NULL;
    myNode* loc=NULL;
    tr.findNode(40,par,loc);
    if(par!=NULL)
    {

        cout<<"parent from main is=="<<par->data<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

It should print below line as well:-
parent from main is==

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten that arguments in C++ by default are passed *by value*.  That means the value of the argument is *copied* into the local variable of the function.

If you want to give back a value to the caller, either return it (like e.g. `std::pair<myNode*, myNode*>`) or pass the pointers *by reference* (e.g. `myNode*& par`).